# How to change the step of volume scroll in VLC?

Tags: mouse, vlc-media-player, scroll-wheel

When I roll the mouse scroll wheel in VLC, the volume changes. But it changes too rapidly: like 83%-70%-58% Can I change the step used like to 1-5% at a time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CTRL+P --> "Show All settings" --> "Audio" --> "Audio output volume step = 6,40"

With this, you get 2% volume step... (1% = 3,20)

Comment: I have tested this in version 2.1.3 and it works ok. But I see that in version 2.0.8 there is a slight difference - as decimals cannot be used - but otherwise it works in the same way.

Comment: For me, VLC scrolls the wrong direction. Scrolling up makes vlc quieter, while i would expect louder, for example. Its so annoying.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, by default it steps volume down by 5% with a value of 12.8.  Changing this to 6.4 steps it down by 2.5% and changing it to 3.2 steps it by 1.25%.  So to get it to step volume by 1% you should change the step number to 2.56.  Just tested it and I get the gratifying granularity of 1% increments.

Comment: As of 2018, this is accurate on VLC 3.0.3. **`12.80`** for **10%** steps (from 0, 5, 10, 15, ..., 100).

Answer (score 0):

The max Value is 256 and it is equal to 100% of Volume in the GUI.
So the single step of 1% is by 2,56. Every thing else is to factoring by multiplication of this Value by your required percent Value for Volume step.